# How to run a drools planner project on jboss as?

Tags: jboss, web, drools-planner

I have desktop application that uses drools planner to generate schedule for my faculty. Now I want to put that on server. So, when I call the method, on server, to create a schedule, I have ClassNotFound Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/planner/core/solution/Solution
```

How can I add Drools library to my EAR? Or do I have to include some jars, and which ones?

Thanks in advance,

Darko

Answer (score 0):

Using ANT or no build system:

- Open the file `drools-planner-*.zip`. Use all the jars from the directory `binaries`. This will include `drools-planner-core-*.jar`, `xstream-*.jar` and a few others.

Using maven, gradle, ivy, ...:

- Depend on `drools-planner-core`.

If you're deploying a war file, then the jars will come under `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: From 5.5.0.Beta1, the planner zip will contain an example war that deploys out-of-the-box on AS 7. In fact, [it's already running on openshift](http://droolsplanner-ge0ffrey.rhcloud.com/droolsplanner/).